# How to pass Python variable to the downstream job in pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have some flow like below in a pipeline.

```
    stage('Build') {
                    build job: 'Build'
    }

    stage('Run') {
                  build job: 'Run', parameters: [string(name: 'build_version', value: <to get from Build job>)]
    }
```

I am running a python script inside Build job as  execute batch script.

````
```python build.py```
````

"build.py" will have a variable "build_version". I want to pass it to jenkins Job "Build" and inturn to the pipeline and pass the same to "Run" job from pipeline.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I have tried setting that value as environment variable using a subprocess call "setx command". But I was not able to find that environment variabkle from jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the efficient solution. But the below method is working for me.

From python script I am creating a property file with the values I need for the next step.
and using EnvInject plugin to push it to environment variables of the build and then with the method "rawBuild.getEnvironment()" in pipeline I am getting it.
Sample code:

```
    def param_val = ""
    stage("Build"){
        def build_var = build job: 'Build'
        param_val = build_var.rawBuild.getEnvironment()[<Variable name you defined>]
     }
    stage("Run") {
         build job: 'Run', parameters: [string(name: '<param>', value: param_val)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution ..

```
def build_version = bat(script: '/path/to/python /path/to/build.py', returnStdout: true)
```

And the python script should write to STDOUT the value that you want assigned to $build_version

Answer (score 0):

Notice that each shell (`sh` step in your pipeline) opens a new shell, without knowing from the previous one. If you want to make your shell variables visible, you would need to `export` the variable.

As a notice here, what I normally do in those cases is not exporting variables (you will need to get it from the env in python), but to "create" an python file containing all variables needed. Later on, your `build.py` script justs import it.

To inject the enviroment variable into that environment python file you can use shell commands (e.g. `cat` or `type`, depending on your OS) or use groovy functions (see [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace))